# Couldn't Deploy Smart Contract on pulsar-2 testnet of Secret Network

Tags: networking, blockchain, smartcontracts

I am building Secret App on pulsar-2 TestNet of Secret Network.

- TestNet .env:

  SECRET_REST_URL='http://testnet.securesecrets.org:1317/'
  SECRET_RPC_URL='https://rpc.pulsar.griptapejs.com/'

  SECRET_CHAIN_ID='pulsar-2'

  MNEMONIC=''
  ADDRESS=''
- Smart Contract in Rust:

  cargo generate --git https://github.com/enigmampc/secret-template --name mysimplecounter

  cd mysimplecounter

  cargo wasm

  ------------ testnet deploy ----------------

  secretcli config node http://testnet.securesecrets.org:1317

  secretcli config chain-id pulsar-2

  secretcli config trust-node true

  secretcli config keyring-backend test

  secretcli keys add

  secretcli query account    (it was not worked as well)

  secretcli tx compute store contract.wasm.gz --from  -y --gas 1000000 --gas-prices=1.0uscrt    (it was not worked as well)

Using above command in terminal of Ubuntu I made testnet account and test smart contract and compiled smart contract.
But last tow commands was not worked in terminal, so that I deployed contract using secret.js in App. What's wrong with these?

Comment: I can't get my secret network contract to work either. This is where I detailed my problem. https://www.reddit.com/r/SecretNetwork/comments/u07hti/i_get_error_could_not_upload_contract_error/. Mine is a little different because it fails with a "{"code":12,"message":"Not Implemented","details":[]} (HTTP 501)" so I'm reasonably sure it's related to the REST API node I'm using.

Comment: Have fix this issue yet? I got the same problem, I can't store the contract